# What to use instead of $.getJSON()

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, reactjs, redux

If you are trying to to use jQuery, specifically in the React/Redux echosystem, what library should take it's place for simple rest calls?  What are developers using instead of **$.getJSON** or **$.postJSON**.

Is there something commonly used that works like node's http module?

Comment: If you're already including jQuery, what's wrong with using `$.getJSON`?

Comment: @AnthonyE I think the OP meant to write "trying **not** to"

Comment: can you get by with a plain `$.get(...)` ?  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: The goal is to include something lightweight for REST calls only.  Also the requirement is no jquery.

Comment: Why not native AJAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like [isomorphic-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-fetch) or [superagent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent)

Answer (score 2):

My favourite library for this is [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios). I find the api to be the clearest and it is very similar to the jQuery style.

Although the fetch api is a huge improvement I don't like sending something to the server and calling it 'fetch'.

As usual with the JS ecosystem there are hundreds of options [xhr on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/xhr) so I'd recommend picking one you like the look of or has been recommended by someone you trust. @Ben's recommendations look great.